# Como pegar Macros váriaveis em uma string

Tags: javascript

Como posso pegar os macros de uma string, da forma que sejam apenas o que tiver entre `[...]`.

Tentei desta forma, mas ela pode ser quebrada, tem alguma forma de fazer usando expressões regulares?

```js
var texto = "HIGHLANDER esse aqui [TESTE] muito massa pra ver se [você recebe sms, [BAR] desconsidere ai, valeu! [FOO]";

var tamanhoDoTexto = texto.length;
var arrayMacros = [];
var abriu = false;

for (var i = 0; i < tamanhoDoTexto; i++) {

  if (texto[i] == "[") {
    abriu = true;
    arrayMacros.push(texto[i]);
  } else if (texto[i] == "]") {
    abriu = false;
    arrayMacros.push(texto[i]);
  } else if (abriu) {
    arrayMacros.push(texto[i]);
  }
}

console.log(arrayMacros.join(""));
```

A saída é: `[TESTE][você recebe sms, [BAR][FOO]` mas deveria ser: `[TESTE][BAR][FOO]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `match` para fazer isso:

```js
var text = "HIGHLANDER esse aqui [TESTE] muito massa pra ver se [você recebe sms, [BAR] desconsidere ai, valeu! [FOO]";

var result = text.match(/\[\w+\]/g);

console.log(result.join(''));
```

Leia mais sobre [regex aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

E sobre o [match aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu precisava, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar regex.match

Segue exemplo no jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nvrkah5e/