# Primeira e última ocorrência de caracter

Tags: javascript, regex

Em JavaScript, como extrair de uma string tudo o que estiver entre a primeira ocorrência de `[` e a ultima ocorrência de `]` ?

Ex:

```
<HR>\n[{"key":"value","key2":["¥"]}]\n<HR>
```

Comment: Você quer dizer  pegar macros? De uma olhada na resposta do Junior Nunes neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197479/como-pegar-macros-v%C3%A1riaveis-em-uma-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar `\[(.*)\]` e depois ir buscar só a parte capturada.
Ou usar `\[.*\]` e fazer um slice à string que isso gera.

Podes ver isso [em funcionamento aqui](https://regex101.com/r/XsISic/1), ou no exemplo:

```js
var string = '<HR>\n[{"key":"value","key2":["¥"]}]\n<HR>';

var semCaptura = /\[.*\]/;
var comCaptura = /\[(.*)\]/;

console.log('semCaptura', string.match(semCaptura)[0].slice(1, -1));
console.log('comCaptura', string.match(comCaptura)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o comando exec da expressão regular. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```js
var regex = /\[(.*)\]/g;
var string = '<HR>\n[{"key":"value","key2":["¥"]}]\n<HR>';

var finds = regex.exec(string);
console.log(finds); // Todas ocorrências encontradas

console.log(finds[1]); //{"key":"value","key2":["¥"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos remover:

- (a) do início até [    `^[^\[]*\[`
- (b) de ] até ao fim `\][^\]]*$`

ou seja replace(`/(a)|(b)/,""`):

```
var n = '<HR>\n[{"key":"value","key2":["¥"]}]\n<HR>';

console.log(n.replace(/^[^\[]*\[|\][^\]]*$/g, ""));
```